# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable in function

Tags: python, typeerror, nonetype

The following (first try of a -) script is a test for me, how to use the return value of one function as the input value for another function.
This works fine:
User can choose a D or W (deposit / withdrawel).
The saldo_actual is (for now) given as 1500.
For evaluate reasons I print (value) between function input_control and function finance_actions.
The values indeed get in the second function.

The results of input with D, W are beneath the code (as well as the TypeErro)

However! the problem >> if the input is empty 5 times, or an other letter then D or W is given, the first value of value as input in the function named: input_control, is None. And this gives a TypeError. I tried different things, but I can't figure out a solution.
Hopefully, you can help me out. Many thanks in advance!! Greetings Jan

```
def input_control():
    
    # Actuele saldo na inleg en opnemen. Begin saldo_actual = 1000 euro.
    saldo_actual = 1500
    # saldo_deposit om aan het einde de klant het totaal gestorte bedrag te laten weten.
    saldo_deposit = 0
    # saldo_withdrawel om aan het einde de klant het totaal opgenomen bedrag te laten weten.
    saldo_withdrawel = 0
    # amount_total het totale verschil tussen saldo_deposit en saldo_withdrawel, in euro's.
    # amount_total wordt bij saldo_actual opgeteld (of afgetrokken.)
    amount_total = 0
    # empty_counter telt aantal keren dat het invoerveld leeg bleef PLUs de keren dat een foutief iets werd ingevoerd.
    attemps = 5
    # transactions_counter: aantal keren dat een transactie gedaan werd. Max = 5
    transactions_counter = 0
    # initieren van de mogelijkheid voor de klant om het programma te stoppen met een q of Q. stop.
    stop = 'a'
    #  saldo_minimum is ondergrens >> zit je aan de grens kan je niet meer opnemen.
    saldo_minimum = -1500
    empty_counter = 0
    letter_definitief = 'a'
      
    while empty_counter < 6:
        
        try:
        
            if empty_counter == 5:
                print("Je probeerde het 5 keer. Terminating Programm.")
                break

            letter_keuze= input('Wat wil je doen? Type D voor deponeren. W voor opnemen.')

            if not letter_keuze:  
                print('niks ingevuld.')
                print()
                empty_counter = empty_counter + 1
                continue


            if  letter_keuze.lower() != 'w' and letter_keuze.lower() != 'd':
                print('Type een W of D of Q als keuze. Nu typte je iets anders')
                print()
                empty_counter = empty_counter + 1
                continue

            if letter_keuze.lower() == 'd' or letter_keuze.lower() == 'w':
                   letter_definitief = letter_keuze.lower()
                    
            return letter_definitief, saldo_actual
                  
        except TypeError:
            print('it is a NoneTYpe')
            break
                     
value = input_control()  
print(value)

letter_definitief = value[0]
saldo_actual = value[1]

def finance_actions(*args):
    print(f'This is in finance_actions: {letter_definitief}.')
    print(f'This is also in finance_actions {saldo_actual}.')
  
finance_actions(letter_definitief, saldo_actual)
```

Result in case of W:

```
Choose D for Deposit and W for withdrawel.w
['w', 1500]
This is in finance_actions: w.
This is also in finance_actions 1500.
```

Result in case of D:

```
Choose D for Deposit and W for withdrawel.d
['d', 1500]
This is in finance_actions: d.
This is also in finance_actions 1500.
```

Result in case of 5 empty enters or 5 other letters:

```
hoose D for Deposit and W for withdrawel.
There was nothing given in.

Choose D for Deposit and W for withdrawel.
There was nothing given in.

Choose D for Deposit and W for withdrawel.
There was nothing given in.

Choose D for Deposit and W for withdrawel.
There was nothing given in.

Choose D for Deposit and W for withdrawel.
There was nothing given in.

Choose D for Deposit and W for withdrawel.
You tried 5 times. Terminating Programm.
None

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-13cc824df307> in <module>
     56 print(value)
     57 
---> 58 letter_definitief = value[0]
     59 saldo_actual = value[1]
     60 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: So clearly `input_control` is going through a path in which it does not `return` anything...so I suggest debugging your program step-by-step using a debugger, such as the one in PyCharm, in order to determine exactly what path through the code is being taken, so that you can see where things start behaving differently than you expect. People here can debug your code for you but you really should be doing it on your own before posting on here. If you have debugged it already then please include that info.

Comment: Your function does not explicitly return anything in that case, and not returning anything is equivalent to returning `None`. You need to check the returned value before using it.

Comment: Random Davis thanks for the suggestion. Good point. I will start using a debugger. Jan

Comment: The point is `input_control` may return None. So you have 2 options: 1) make sure it will never return None (change the implementation of the function) 2) make sure the caller code woll check the return value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is throwing type error because the value of 'value' is None.
to avoid getting this error try-

```
if value != None:
 letter_definitief = value[0]
 saldo_actual = value[1]

 def finance_actions(*args):
    print(f'This is in finance_actions: {letter_definitief}.')
    print(f'This is also in finance_actions {saldo_actual}.')
  
 finance_actions(letter_definitief, saldo_actual)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `value` is `None`, then you shouldn't be running `finance_actions`. Replace this code:

```
letter_definitief = value[0]
saldo_actual = value[1]

def finance_actions(*args):
    print(f'This is in finance_actions: {letter_definitief}.')
    print(f'This is also in finance_actions {saldo_actual}.')
  
finance_actions(letter_definitief, saldo_actual)
```

with this code:

```
def finance_actions(*args):
    print(f'This is in finance_actions: {letter_definitief}.')
    print(f'This is also in finance_actions {saldo_actual}.')
  
if value:
    finance_actions(value)
else:
    #insert error message here
```